# Cross-platform password manager that syncs with iCloud Keychain?

Tags: keychain, macos, software-recommendation

I am currently using the macOS/iCloud Keychain as my main password manger, and have been for ~20 years. It's of course great with Safari and iOS apps, but not ideal when using multiple browsers, an Android phone, a Windows PC and other devices.

Is there a password manager that ALSO syncs any password it manages with the macOS keychain?

I am thinking of a natural migration from Keychain to a cross-platform, cross-browser solution, over a couple of months.

Comment: NOTE: There are a couple of existing questions specific to Chrome integration and to migration/export to another cloud-based password manager. This is not helping in my case.

Comment: I don't think Apple write Keychain to work on Android or Windows...

Comment: @SolarMike Of course, then Keychain Access would be the password manager I am looking for.